# Injecting a File in Spring Java Config

Tags: spring-security, spring-saml

I am trying to configure SAML authentication using `Spring's SAML extension`. While trying it in the annotation way using `Java Configuration`. I have a requirement of getting the `IDP metadata file` and the `SP metadata file` to create the `metadataManager` bean.

Here is the relevant configuration:

```
@Bean(name="idpMetadata")
public ExtendedMetadataDelegate idpMetaData(){
    FilesystemMetadataProvider metadataProvider = null;
    try {
        metadataProvider = new FilesystemMetadataProvider(idpMetadataFile);
        metadataProvider.setParserPool(parserPool());
    }
    catch (MetadataProviderException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ExtendedMetadataDelegate metaDataDelegate = 
        new ExtendedMetadataDelegate(metadataProvider, new ExtendedMetadata());
    return metaDataDelegate;
}

@Bean(name="spMetadata")
public ExtendedMetadataDelegate spMetaData(){
    FilesystemMetadataProvider metadataProvider = null;
    try {
        metadataProvider = new FilesystemMetadataProvider(spMetadataFile);
        metadataProvider.setParserPool(parserPool());
    }
    catch (MetadataProviderException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ExtendedMetadata extendedMetadata = new ExtendedMetadata();
    extendedMetadata.setLocal(true);
    extendedMetadata.setAlias("defaultAlias");
    extendedMetadata.setSecurityProfile("metaiop");
    extendedMetadata.setSslSecurityProfile("pkix");
    extendedMetadata.setRequireArtifactResolveSigned(true);
    extendedMetadata.setRequireLogoutRequestSigned(true);
    extendedMetadata.setRequireLogoutResponseSigned(false);
    extendedMetadata.setIdpDiscoveryEnabled(false);

    ExtendedMetadataDelegate metaDataDelegate = 
        new ExtendedMetadataDelegate(metadataProvider, extendedMetadata);
    return metaDataDelegate;
}
```

My problem is I am not able to get the file content here. The `spMetadataFile` and the `idpMetadataFile` are null. I am not sure how can I inject or get old of these files if stored in the classpath of the project.

Please help.

Comment: it is not clear how spMetadataFile and idpMetadataFile are populated but it seems you can autowire ResourceLoader and use it like resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:filepath").getFile(); to get a file.

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine on my own SP-implementation:

```
@Bean
@Qualifier("yourMetadataProvider")
public ExtendedMetadataDelegate yourMetadataProvider()
        throws MetadataProviderException, IOException {
    String path = "<metadata_path>";
    FilesystemMetadataProvider filesystemMetadataProvider = new FilesystemMetadataProvider(
            new File(path));
    filesystemMetadataProvider.setParserPool(parserPool());
    ExtendedMetadataDelegate emd = new ExtendedMetadataDelegate(
            filesystemMetadataProvider, new ExtendedMetadata());

    // Your config
    emd.setLocal(true);
    emd.setAlias("defaultAlias");
    emd.setSecurityProfile("metaiop");
    emd.setSslSecurityProfile("pkix");
    emd.setRequireArtifactResolveSigned(true);
    emd.setRequireLogoutRequestSigned(true);
    emd.setRequireLogoutResponseSigned(false);
    emd.setIdpDiscoveryEnabled(false);

    return emd;
}
```

Be careful when setting the path of your metadata file.